# Css ignoring class rules

Tags: html, css, css-specificity

Very basic question but it seems my CSS is ignoring my class rules and still applying padding to the left and to the right:

http://jsfiddle.net/VabWL/11/

This makes it drop off the end. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here please?

```
#num {float: left; background: pink; width: 16.8%; text-align: center; margin: 2%;}
.first {margin-left: 0px; background: blue; height: 50px;}
.last {margin-right: 0px;}

<div id="num" class="first">0</div>
<div id="num">1</div>
<div id="num">4</div>
<div id="num">6</div>
<div id="num" class="last">9</div>
```

Comment: Your total %s are adding up to 104% of the width of your page. (16.8%x5)+(2%x5)+(2%x5)=104% Also, http://jsfiddle.net/VabWL/13/ for a fixed class/ID situation.

Comment: General rule of computing (and life) is that IDs are meant to be **unique**

Comment: You should [read this](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/), it's a good explanation on css specifity

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An `id` selector is more [specific](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) than a `class` selector so will be applied last in the [cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade).

`id`s have to be unique, so your HTML is invalid anyway. Use classes throughout instead.

```
<div class="num first">0</div>
<div class="num">1</div>
<div class="num">4</div>
<div class="num">6</div>
<div class="num last">9</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this work?

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/VabWL/18/)

**CSS**

```
* { 
    padding: 0px; 
    margin: 0px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow:hidden;
}

div {
    float: left;
    background: pink; 
    width: calc(92%/5);
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 2%;
}

.last {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The `id` styling takes priority over the `class`.

Try adding `!important` to the end of each CSS property of the classes to prioritise it.

```
.first {margin-left: 0px !important; background: blue !important; height: 50px !important;}
.last {margin-right: 0px !important;}
```

Comment: `!important` is a sledgehammer of a solution with no layers of nuance, once you've used it you can't double it up when the problem occurs again. It should be the very last resort.

Comment: What's with the downvotes? It might not be the best solution, but it's still valid CSS.